# Java classes won't open in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've tried cleaning and validating my project, restarting both Eclipse and my computer and my java class files won't open in the editor. Also, I've tried deleting the project from my workspace and reimporting it and no luck. Does anyone know what it might be?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun - Sorry, .java

Comment: right in my project explorer

Comment: What do you mean by "won't open"? Do you get error or what?

Comment: @MarounMaroun nothing in my console.. i've tried both double clicking and right click -> open with

Comment: Look in the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory for messages (or look in the `Error Log` view).

Comment: @greg-449 a workspace crash was detected.. that might be because i forced quit the eclipse process though. that's the only error i see

Answer (score 6):

Window -> Reset Perspective worked for me

Comment: That worked for me! thanks! Just adding more detail: Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective...

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Right Click on File -> Open With -> Java Editor`

[image]

Make sure you are in the `Java perspective.`

[image]

Try cleaning eclipse. Start eclipse with

```
eclipse --clean
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird because I was just doing some work and it started out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that a single click is selected for open mode. if you go to preference setting, it will be the first thing you will see

[image]